# Using cucumber to test an API not written in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, node.js, cucumber, bdd

I'm writing an API using a non-rails framework. I normally use Cucumber for BDD and testing of API's when I'm writing them in RAILS.

Is there a strong reason not to use Cucumber when I'm testing an API written on top of node.js (or any other framework, really)?

Strong technical reasons to not do this might include:

- Dependency of Cucumber on Rails
- The existence of a better framework for node.js
- Some other technical reason I don't know about.

Comment: As an open source project contributor I would rage if I had to get rails to run unit tests for a node.js project.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Cucumber doesn't depend on Rails.

I have been trying out some different javascript testing frameworks to try to work out what I want to use. So far I like mocha with expect.js for unit testing but I haven't found anything for integration testing a node app that I'm happy with. It's possible to do with mocha and supertest, and I've also tried cucumber.js which is getting there but it's not as mature as the Ruby version - so that's what I intend to use.

I can't think of a good reason not to do this, apart from it may be harder to do things like set up fixtures - but that may well be a good thing as it would force your tests to deal only with the public interface of your API - as it was intended to be used.

Answer (score 1):

As said cucumber has nothing to do with rails.
You could perfectly use it to test API's written in any languages.

In case you want to use node.js full stack [cucumber.js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) is a good option.